# array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array - Manually Creating A Paginator

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am trying to union 3 SQL query, so I can orderBy the duedates as newDate and make a manually create paginator.

But for some reason is throwing this exception:

> array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

my code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $TMUDue = Equipments::Where('due1', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                            ->select('*', 'due1 AS newDate');
    $CalDue = Equipments::Where('due2', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                            ->select('*', 'due2 AS newDate');
    $SerDue = Equipments::Where('due3', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                            ->select('*', 'due3 AS newDate');

    $equipmentsDue = $SerDue->union($CalDue)->union($TMUDue)->orderBy('newDate')->get();

    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $paginate = 10;

    $offSet = ($page * $paginate) - $paginate;
    $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($equipmentsDue, $offSet, $paginate, true);
    $equipmentsDue = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($equipmentsDue), $paginate, $page);
    return view('dashboard.index', compact('equipmentsDue'));
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Without manually creation of the database pagination the query works fine.

Comment: what is output of $equipmentsDue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says that you need to pass array instead collection , so change it with [`->toArray();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)

```
$equipmentsDue = $SerDue->union($CalDue)
->union($TMUDue)->orderBy($sort , $sort2)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: and voilà! Thanks lots dude